# drop a marker on another marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My app shows two kinds of markers: locations and items. I would like to be able to drag and drop items onto locations.

But when a marker is dragged, the `mouseover` event on the markers it is dragged over are not triggered.

If someone know a way to create this effect, I'd be eternally greatfull :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to implement it based on distance to the target, either real world distance in meters or screen distance in pixels.
For example:

```
var locations = Array();
var items = Array();
```

and then:

```
var itemMarker = new google.maps.Marker(opts);
google.maps.event.addListener(itemMarker, 'drag', function(){
    for( var n = 0; n < locations.length; n++){
    var d = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this.getPosition(),locations[n].getPosition());
     if (d < 5){
         // do something when below a given threshold.
     }
    }
});
items.push(itemMarker);
```

Demo here:

http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_template_simple.html
(Drag the Omaha marker towards Chicago.)
Remember to load the geometry library when you load the API.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar but its less elegant, with an additional object. In my solution each location gets a drop zone circle. The diameter of the circle is calculated like so: Math.pow(2, 21 - map.getZoom()) / 2 this is what your 5 stands for.

Comment: The value of 5 means nothing special. It was just an example. Glad it worked out for you. :-)

Comment: the 5 is the distance between the two markers. But you need to increase the distance in order to account for lower zoom level. This is why I replaced the 5 with Math.pow(2, 21 - map.getZoom()) / 2 This way the circle is smaller in meters but stays the same size on screen when you zoom in